# Replace line in variable with string in shell script

Tags: bash, replace

How can I replace the entire line `0 6 * * 0 /root/SST/myscript.sh` with an updated string?

The script will be run using `update.sh 7` whereby `0 6 * * 0 /root/SST/myscript.sh` will be replaced with `0 7 * * 0 /root/SST/myscript.sh`

The `hour` cron entry will be dynamic (it can change), therefore some sort of wildcard in the regular expression may be useful, `0 * * * 0 /root/SST/myscript.sh`?

```
[root@local ~]# crontab -l    
0 1 * * 0 /root/SST/test.sh
0 6 * * 0 /root/SST/myscript.sh
0 10 * * 0 /root/SST/test.sh
```

Shell script contents `update.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(crontab -l)

if [[ "$tmpfile" == *myscript.sh* ]]
then
    #update myscript.sh within crontab contents

    echo "$updatedfileContents";
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this answer in the end `./update.sh 8`

```
#!/bin/bash

updatedCrontab=""
tmpfile=$(crontab -l)

while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == *myscript.sh* ]]
    then
            updatedCrontab+="0 $1 * * 0 myscript.sh\n"
    else
            updatedCrontab+="$line\n"
    fi
done <<< "$tmpfile"

echo -e "$updatedCrontab" | crontab
```

Result:

```
[root@local ~]# crontab -l
0 1 * * 0 /root/SST/test.sh
0 8 * * 0 /root/SST/myscript.sh
0 10 * * 0 /root/SST/test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
crontab -l |
sed '/myscript.sh/ s/^\([^ ][^ ]*\) [^ ][^ ]* /\1 '"$1" '/'
```

This will show the updated contents.  The pattern matches and remembers a sequence of non-blanks at the start of the line, followed by a blank, a sequence of one or more non-blanks, and another blank, and replaces that with the remembered pattern, a space, the value in `$1` and a blank.  If you use `update.sh 7,8,9,10,11`, then you get `0 7,8,9,10,11` in your crontab.

You can capture the output of that command in a variable and then echo it (carefully; use double quotes) into `crontab` to change the actual entry.

It is conceivable that you could do:

```
crontab -l |
sed '/myscript.sh/ s/^\([^ ][^ ]*\) [^ ][^ ]* /\1 '"$1" '/' |
(sleep 1; crontab)
```

The `sleep` gives `crontab -l` a chance to fetch the current value before it is clobbered by the new value — probably!  It's probably worth thinking about keeping your crontab under a VCS (version control system) to avoid losing it — especially if you try the `sleep` trick.

Comment: What if the original crontab entry is `9 6 * * 0 /root/SST/myscript.sh` .. it will not always contain at 0 at the beginning